# Does TFS work without a domain?

Tags: security, tfs

I installed TFS on a single W7 machine with a single user (me).

After creating a collection, I am unable to access it or to administer its security: It asks me for credentials. However, since I created the collection and there is only one user, I am stuck.

I am thinking it may fail because it's a single machine without domain (and therefore uses NTLM)

Has anyone been able to use TFS on a single non domain machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx) says that it is a bit tricky to use TFS without domain, but possible:

> Local user accounts must be created on
>   the Team Foundation server for all
>   users requiring access to the server.
>   **Local user accounts must be added to
>   Team Foundation Server server-level
>   and project-level groups** so that the
>   users are authorized on the Team
>   Foundation server. When connecting
>   from a Team Foundation client, such as
>   Team Explorer, in the workgroup, the
>   client user account credentials must
>   match those of the server, or the user
>   will be prompted for a user name and
>   password for an account on the Team
>   Foundation Server.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to setup shadow accounts to get authentication to work reasonably, but once you do that it should work just fine. Remember that you'll need to run your build service as one of those shadow accounts to (rather than the default Network Service account).